# net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND en la consola -Javascript

Tags: javascript, imagen, consola

Hola estoy realizando un listado donde es posible que el usuario pueda agregar mas card a la lista. Las mismas se guardan en el localStorage pero me salta un error en consola al cargar las imagenes (texto si recupera) cuando salgo de la pagina y vuelvo a ingresar (Recargando la pagina si s e puede visualizar), el problema es cuando CIERRO.

Comparto repo:

https://github.com/RaquelReedemed/carritoPractica

[image: Error en consola]

Comment: Hola y bienvenida. Debes incluir el código en la pregunta en lugar de usar enlaces a sitios externos. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la forma en que debes publicar tus preguntas y así evitas que te las cierren.

Comment: Hola, gracias por el consejo y tomare en cuenta para proximas publicaciones. Saludos,

Comment: Un poco tarde, pero: no lo tengas en cuenta para _siguientes publicaciones_, corrige la actual. Recuerda que los enlaces más adelante pueden caer, por lo tanto el contenido central de la pregunta se perderá. Ten presente que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino para otros usuarios que más adelante podrían tener un problema similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copie tu código y lo corrí en mi equipo, el problema que me dio a mi es que no me cargaba las imágenes de los productos nuevos que creas con el modal, solo se mostraba el texto, los datos del LocalStorage se cargan y leen bien. El 'file not found' me viene de un 'sweetalert' pero no afecta al funcionamiento de la página. Lo de las imágenes lo arregle cambiando tu funcion `importImg()`:

```
function importImg(event) {
    let fr = new FileReader(); // uso de la api filereader
    fr.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
    fr.addEventListener('load',() => {
        imgSelected = fr.result;
        console.log(fr.result)
    })
//   tu codigo:
//   const currentImg = event.target.files[0];
//   console.log("jasdjasd")
//   const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(currentImg);
//   console.log(currentImg)
//   console.log(objectURL)
//   imgSelected = objectURL;
}
```

A partir de eso funciona perfecto, muestra las imágenes y las carga aunque cierre la página y abra de nuevo, aunque haga un hard refresh (recargar borrando cache) haciendo un refresh normal carga todo bien, lo único es que tarda mucho en leer los datos del localStorage porque desde que abro la página hasta que se muestran las cards con los productos pasan como 20 segundos.

Esa función fue lo único que toque, si no te funciona tu problema debe estar en otro lado.

Comment: Hola!, me funciono excelente la funcion y no tenia conocimiento sobre la api fileReader() y estare buscando mas info sobre ella ya que es super interesante. En cuanto a la funcionalidad cuando cierro la pagina no muestra el card agregada usando CRHOME pero cuando uso BRAVE muestra perfectamente! y la verdad nose a que se debera, pense que eran iguale pero al parecer tienen algunas diferencias para que ejecute alguna funcion en uno y en otro no. Agradedezto el tiempo que tomaste para ayudarme :) . Saludos y que tengas un lindo dia!

Comment: @RaquelReedemed quizás se deba a alguna extensión que tenés instalada en Chrome! A veces pueden inyectar código en tus archivos a la hora de ejecutarlos. De nada y que tengas un lindo día vos también :)